# Empty window in HM NIS Edit language-choose-window for NSI-Script Wizard: How can I select languages and fix the error?

Tags: nsis

HM NIS EDIT don't show languages?

When I want to make a NSI-Script with the Wizard from HM NIS EDIT, the wizard don't show the languages In the language-choose-window. Instead, there's a empty window. When I click to Next, it shows an error who tells me that I have to choose some languages.
What I could do that it works?
Thanks for help!

I tried to create a NSI Script with the Wizard from HM NIS Edit, but the window of the language-selection is empty. I tried to click on next, but it shows an error who tells that I have to select some languages.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in HM NIS Edit generator.

HM NIS Edit is deprecated, this tool is not in active development for 18 years (last release in 2005).
It does not work with modern Windows and recent versions of NSIS, **so there is nothing we can do** to fix the script generating within it.

If you have some (partial) script generated by HM simply edit it in your preferred text editor (see https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Category:Development_Environments, many modern IDEs are supported).

If you need a help from this community post the script here so we can have a look on it.